# How to Block ADs on Spotify (Android) with a local VPN?

Tags: spotify, ads

Is it possible to block ADs on Android Spotify by using an Ad blocking (local) VPN? I have the feeling that Spotify is streaming ads https encrypted over the same server as music since adguard can't filter them

Comment: [comment copied over after migration] I've found myself that the Spotify apps on both iOS & macOS can get adverts past AdGuard. It can't get them past the same AdGuard on Safari on the Mac & fewer on Safari on iPhone. [Same for Farcebork, btw]

Comment: VPN based ad blocker can only block ads that are delivered from a domain that is only used for ads. Otherwise functionality provided by the domain would not be available. Additionally VPN based blocker have to maintain a list of those domains that should be blocked. If the service changes the domains frequently then VPN based blockers have problems blocking all of those domains.

Comment: Maybe a specified app like [SpotMute](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.developments.samu.muteforspotify) or [Ad-Silence](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bluepie.ad_silence) can help with that? The latter is also [available at F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/packages/bluepie.ad_silence/).